# Wicket - DropDownChoice - titles (tooltips) for options

Tags: java, wicket

Is there a way to have the DropDownChoice in Wicket assign tooltips (e.g. title attributes) to individual option elements?

I have selectbox items in the following form:

```
public class SelectBoxItem
{
    private Long id;
    private String label;
    private String description;
}
```

All items are loaded from the database.

I configure the DropDownChoice component using a ChoiceRenderer to use the ids as keys and the labels as values.

Now I would need to configure it  to use the descriptions as tooltip messages as well.

---

I have only found [this related thread](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/wicket-users/201012.mbox/%3C1291233028966-3067946.post@n4.nabble.com%3E) on the Internet. Browsing the relevant Wicket classes let me to the same conclusions as the author, e.g. that this was probably not possible with the current versions of the DropDownChoice/ChoiceRenderer classes. Is that right? And in that case, is there a similar component which would allow that?

---

(For a more comprehensive description of my code base see [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226118/wicket-dropdownchoice-choicerenderer-preselecting-does-not-work) where I asked about a different problem within the same context.)

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution for this problem. Many thanks to Andrea Del Bene for the advice.

```
public class TitledDropDownChoice<T> extends DropDownChoice<T> {

//  ... constructors from superclass ...

@Override
protected void appendOptionHtml(AppendingStringBuffer buffer,
        T choice, int index, String selected) {

    super.appendOptionHtml(buffer, choice, index, selected);

    // converts <option value="foo">bar</option> to
    // <option value="foo" title="bar">bar</option>
    String replString = "value=\"" + getChoiceRenderer()
        .getIdValue(choice, index) + "\"";
    int pos = buffer.indexOf(replString);
    buffer.insert(pos + replString.length(), 
        " title=\"" + getChoiceRenderer().getDisplayValue(choice) + "\"");

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried overriding method appendOptionHtml? You could use it to append the desired html (i.e. title="toolTipText").